# Calculus: finding integral

Tags: calculus

I need to compute the following two integrals: $$\int_0^{\infty}y^be^{-y/2} dy$$

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}dy$$  can I do this?  Please show me the process.
How to use definition of gamma function to solve these?

Comment: 1).  Integration by parts b times.

Comment: How to use definition of gramma function to solve these?

Comment: The first integral is different now.  It was $e^{y/2}$ earlier.

Comment: the second integral is the standard normal distribution with area 1 on the interval  $(\infty,\infty)$.  So your integral from $(0,\infty)$ is. 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first integral, substitute $u=y/2$ with $2du=dy$ to get:

$$ 2^{b+1}\int_0^{\infty}u^be^{-u}du = 2^{b+1}\Gamma(b+1)$$

from the definition of the gamma function.

The second integral is a Gaussian integral, so I will not try to replicate what has been done so well before.

EDIT:

I see you want to use the definition of the gamma function.

For the second integral, let $u=y^2/2$ with $du=ydy$ to get:

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty u^{-1/2}e^{-u}du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(1/2)$$

Since $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$, you get $1/2$ as a final answer. Of course finding $\Gamma(1/2)$ is another story.

**Finding $\Gamma(1/2)$**

The most logical way in your case is to go back, evaluate the second integral as a Gaussian integral, and then compare results. You can find online many good derivations of the Gaussian integral. I [found this one well-explained](http://www.umich.edu/~chem461/Gaussian%20Integrals.pdf).

But if you assume known the reflection property of the gamma function:

$$\Gamma(1-z) \Gamma(z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$$

you can set $z = 1/2$ to get $\Gamma(1/2)^2=\pi$ or $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Based in your calculation on question 1, the answer is 2^(b+1)*b!, right. However, the answer my professor gave is 1. I am wondering how could that be?

Comment: How could you calculate gamma symbol which looks like F(1/2) = pi?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf I have added a section to my answer about your addition. Is there anything more? If your question is answered, consider accepting the answer.